# What are TLS Cipher Suites with ephemeral key Exchange and NULL encryption for

Tags: encryption, tls, authentication

I wonder about the benefits of the following ciphers:

- TLS_ECDHE_PSK_WITH_NULL_SHA256
- TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA

Why should I go for perfect forward secrecy if I don't want to encrypt in the first place? I just want to go for Authenticity/Integrity..

Why are those ciphers even listed in the registry? Is it for the sake of completeness or am I overlooking important use cases?

Comment: I think I can construct a case where that's useful: developer-testing an application that chatters over TLS. Say you want to view / debug the network traffic but can't / don't want to give wireshark the server private key.

Answer (score 2):

The NULL encryption was introduced after RFC 4785 which was introduced support for different import restrictions among other things:

Quoting the RFC:

> There are also cases when confidentiality is not permitted -
> e.g., for implementations that must meet import restrictions in some
> countries.  Even though no encryption is used, these ciphersuites
> support authentication of the client and server to each other, and
> message integrity.

Reference: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4785

> 

The ciphersuites defined in this document are intended for a rather
limited set of applications, usually involving only a very small
number of clients and servers.  Even in such environments, other
alternatives may be more appropriate.

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear enough: **why** is there is a cipher suite for exchanging keys with **ephemeral** DH, if no Encryption is desired?  (EC)DH**E**.xxx.WITH_NULL

Comment: My guess is that this key exchange is done for generating the keys for authentication

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, they exist for completeness only.   The PSK cipher suites (and there are several of them) first defined in [RFC 5489](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5489.txt) without meaningful comment, only:

> The following cipher suite matches the cipher suites defined in
>      Section 3.1, except that we define a suite with NULL encryption.

and similar.

The ECDHE_ECDSA cipher suite definition is even less verbose, with no comment at all, but it's clear from looking at the definition in [RFC 4492](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4492.txt) that the situation is the same.  The list of cipher suites being defined is simple a repeating list enumerating each combination of supported key exchange, authentication, and encryption algorithm, including NULL.

Comment: So it' really is just there for completeness? I could see that being useful for developers trying to test / wireshark their TLS connections, but it's likely that there's no possible reason to use it in production?

Comment: @MikeOunsworth I would agree that is probably the case. I certainly haven't been able to find a compelling reason for using them outside of dev/testing documented anywhere.